# XML Serialization Loses namespaces

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have a CRM entity XML message as follows:

```
<c:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType xmlns:c="ns1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  >
....
 <c:value i:type="**b:AliasedValue**" **xmlns:b="ns3"**>
 SomethingHere...
 </c:value>
</c:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```

Then I deserialized it to an object and serialized back to xml
I get

```
<c:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType xmlns:c="ns1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   instance"  >
 <c:value i:type="b:AliasedValue" >
 SomethingHere...
</c:value>
</c:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```

I loose the xmlns:b definition.
Any idea why?

Comment: Just a guess (however somewhat educated), but the 'b' namespace isn't actually used in an element, just as a value in a attribute. Don't know too much about .net XML libs, but there should be an option to not strip "unused" namespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forty-two is right: attribute values do not carry any default semantics, so the namespace usage isn't recognized as such by xml processors.

if you wish to refer to some `b`-data in your `i:type`-attribute, you my use a mapping element  to associate `c:value` with a (hypothesized) `b:value`, i.e.:

```
<mapping xml:id="idXY'/>
...
<c:value c:ref="idXY">...</c:value>
...
<b:value b:ref="idXY">...</b:value>
...
```

... where you would declare `_:ref` as IDREF attributes in the respective xml schemas. you may have to adjust the design for 1:n-/m:n - mappings e.g. by having referrers as child elements of `_:value`.

best regards, carsten